# Make URL like /fr/something display same as /something

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect

I would like every URL of my WordPress site that looks like `/fr/something` to show exactly the same page as `/something`, but **without redirecting**; I want to keep the URL.

I think I'm close, I used :

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'init', 'my_flush_rules' );

// flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules() {
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );        
    if ( ! isset( $rules['fr(\/(.*))?$'] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}        
// Adding a new rule
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['fr(\/(.*))?$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}        
// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function my_insert_query_vars( $vars ) {
    array_push( $vars, 'id' );
    return $vars;
}
```

It works on some URLs but not all :

- `/fr` shows the same as `/` => Fine
- `/fr/page-d-example` shows the same as `/page-d-example` => Fine
- `/fr/2015/09/25/bonjour-tout-le-monde/` redirects to
  `/2015/09/25/bonjour-tout-le-monde/` => Not fine

Do you know why the last one is redirecting and how to prevent that?

Comment: In your `rewrite_rules_array` filter you can look at `$rules` and see everything you'd need to duplicate. There are a lot of them- single posts, author archives, date archives, taxonomy archives, post formats, attachments, plus pagination and feeds for all of them.

Comment: Ok that worked, I ended up with : 

function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
 $newrules = array();
 foreach($rules as $k => $r) {
  $newrules['fr/'.$k] = $r;
 }
 $newrules['fr/?'] = '/index.php';
 return $newrules + $rules;
}

I had to manually add the last rule for just 'fr/' url

Comment: Glad you solved it! Please add your final code as an answer and accept it so it may help future visitors, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Milo's advice set Mansur Khan in the right direction:

> In your `rewrite_rules_array` filter you can look at `$rules` and see
>   everything you'd need to duplicate. There are a lot of them- single
>   posts, author archives, date archives, taxonomy archives, post
>   formats, attachments, plus pagination and feeds for all of them.

The updated, working code:

> ```
> add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
> add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_insert_query_vars' );
> add_action( 'init', 'my_flush_rules' );
>
> // flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
> function my_flush_rules() {
>     $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );        
>     if ( ! isset( $rules['fr(\/(.*))?$'] ) ) {
>         global $wp_rewrite;
>         $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
>     }
> }   
>
> // Adding a new rule
> function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
>   $newrules = array();
>   foreach( $rules as $k => $r ) {
>       $newrules['fr/'.$k] = $r;
>   }
>
>   $newrules['fr/?'] = '/index.php';
>
>   return $newrules + $rules;
> }
>
> // Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
> function my_insert_query_vars( $vars ) {
>     array_push( $vars, 'id' );
>     return $vars;
> }
> ```